# Extracting 5 fields from logfile containing a string in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, regex-group

Below is a sample log file data:

```
08/22/2018 02:50:06.380 EDT-0400 2 TCP/IP Controller Plugin.Transmitter pool thread <Regular:2>.CybTargetHandlerChannel.call[:695] - Message has been sent: 20180822 02500636+0400 C7STA PLINUX03 ALOPMTA2.N01834/LO.S00001D182340248/MAIN State EXEC SetStart Status(Executing at PLINUX03) Jobno(34523) ChildPid(34527)  User(PLINUX03) Host(localhost)
08/22/2018 02:50:06.382 EDT-0400 5 TCP/IP Controller Plugin.Transmitter pool thread <Regular:2>.CybTargetHandlerChannelLogHelper.logConnectionClose[:133] - Conversation with C7STA closed
08/22/2018 02:51:21.761 EDT-0400 5 TCP/IP Controller Plugin.Transmitter pool thread <Regular:1>.CybTargetHandlerChannel.call[:666] - Attempting to send:    20180822 02512176+0400 C7STA PLINUX03 ALOECPC7.N01745/LO.S00002D182340242/MAIN State COMPLETE Cmpc(0) SetEnd  User(PLINUX03) Host(localhost)
08/22/2018 02:51:21.771 EDT-0400 2 TCP/IP Controller Plugin.Transmitter pool thread <Regular:1>.CybTargetHandlerChannel.call[:695] - Message has been sent: 20180822 02512176+0400 C7STA PLINUX03 ALOECPC7.N01745/LO.S00002D182340242/MAIN State COMPLETE Cmpc(0) SetEnd  User(PLINUX03) Host(localhost)
```

I was trying to extract five fields below from the first and fourth line which contains "Message has been sent":

1. TimeStamps: 20180822 02500636+0400, 20180822 02512176+0400
2. JobNames : ALOPMTA2,ALOECPC7
3. JobNumbers : 01834,1745
4. Users : User(PLINUX03), User(PLINUX03)
5. Statuses : MAIN State EXEC SetStart, MAIN State COMPLETE

I was able to filter lines containing "Message has been sent:" using below expression, but was not sure on extracting 5 fields from this line:

```
^.*\b(Message has been sent:.)\b.*$
```

Can someone help? This is for extraction on Splunk. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, I've edited that in for you. Hopefully someone can help. What have you tried so far, and what guides or other resources have you been reading?

Comment: I am new to regex and was able to filter out the first and four lines using the below code:
^.*\b(Message has been sent:.)\b.*$
I was using regexer for some quick trial and error, but couldn't pin point in fetching the five fields

Comment: I'm not familiar with splunk. Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.1.2/SearchReference/Regex) for instance?

Comment: Yes, it said that the regex needs to be Perl compatible. Should i add Perl also as a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this regex :

```
Message has been sent: (?<timestamp>\d{8}\s\d{8}\+\d{4})\s\w+\s\w+\s(?<jobname>\w+)\.N(?<jobnumber>\d+)\/[^\/]+\/(?<statuses>(\w+\s)+)\w+\(.+User\((?<user>\w+)\)
```

- Group 'timestamp' `(\d{8}\s\d{8}\+\d{4})` : matches the timestamps
- Group 'jobname' `\s(\w+)\.N` : matches the jobs names
- Group 'jobnumber' `\.N(\d+)\/` : matches the jobs numbers
- Group 'statuses' `((\w+\s)+)` : matches the statuses
- Group 'user' `User\((\w+)\)` : matches the users

You can see an example here with the data you provided : https://regex101.com/r/G6GD46/4

Do not hesitate to play with this example to get the result you need.

Tell me if you need more explanation for these regexs'.

**Edit:** as suggested by @RichG in the comments, I've added named groups to allow Splunk to extract groups as variables.

Comment: Include group names in the regex string so Splunk will extract fields.
`index=foo "Message has been sent" | rex "sent: (?<Date>\d{8}\s\d{8}\+\d{4})\s\w+\s\w+\s(?<jobName>\w+)\.N(?<jobNum>\d+)\/[^\/]+\/(?<Status>(\w+\s)+)\w+\(.+User\((?<User>\w+)\)" | ...`